# How to troubleshoot a NullPointerException on Android?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

My program is immediately crashing on my Android Emulator and I receive this in the Eclipse Console:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:572)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHELO(HandleHello.java:142)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHelloCommands(HandleHello.java:65)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.getJdwpPacket(Client.java:671)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:317)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)
```

**How can I troubleshoot what is throwing this message?**  I'm new to Eclipse and Android.

The program completely crashes when I try to launch a dialog with a button, and refers back here:

```
    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        Dialog dialog;
        switch (id) {
        case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
            return new TimePickerDialog(this,
                    mTimeSetListener, mHour24, mMinute, false);


        case POWER_OFF_OPTIONS:
            AlertDialog.Builder builder;
            AlertDialog alertDialog;

            Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.options,
                    (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1));
            //Capture view elements
            mChkAudio = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkAudio);
            mChkBluetooth = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkBlueTooth);
            mChkNetwork = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkNetwork);
            mChkWifi = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkWifi);
            mBtnOK = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOK);
            mBtnOK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                  DismissPowerOptions();
                    }
            }); 
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
            builder.setView(layout);
            alertDialog = builder.create();
            //return alertDialog;
        default:
            dialog = null;
        }
        return dialog;
    }
```

Comment: before anything check your line 142 at your HandleHello Activity class.

Comment: I would like to see answers focusing on **how to troubleshoot** this in Android. I don't do Android development -- but what are some tools (e.g. debuggers or static analyzers or methodologies) that can be used to find out what is wrong in a repeatable manner on the Android platform?

Comment: I have a warning there, but no errors:  The static field AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM should be accessed in a static way

Comment: Yes, when accessing a static member always use the type name as the receiver: `TheType.StaticMember` (good) instead of `TheType t = new TheType(); t.StaticMember` (bad). (If in the applicable scope then `StaticMember` can be let un-prefixed, of course).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is not coming from your program.   It is a problem with an Eclipse plugin for Android: The "Dalvik Debug Monitor Server".

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html

Sometimes these things just get into a bad state and need to be restarted.  Close the emulator and restart Eclipse.  Start the emulator from the AVD Manager window using the button labelled "Start..".  In the start dialog select the "WIPE ALL DATA" button to be sure you're getting a clean start.

If that doesn't solve it then try deleting your emulator in the AVD Manager and creating a new one.

Comment: I did in fact have a problem with my emulator.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you've not [configured your](http://kennithleung.com/blog/2011/02/26/fix-android-null-pointer-exception/) AVD properly

Answer (score 0):

i solved this problem by click on INVALIDATE CACHE AND RESTART.

file -> Invalidate cache and restart ->invalidate and restart